# convert COleDateTime to ticks or integer representation

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

how to convert COleDateTime to some sort of integer representation which can be easily converted back.

Comment: COleDateTime::m_dt stores a double that represents the number of days relative to midnight December 30, 1899. If you convert to int you are losing precision.

Comment: You can cast that double to 64-bit integer if you don't care about the value except the task of reverse conversion.

Answer (score 5):

I think the simplest way is through `COleDateTimeSpan` as follow:

```
// Create an epoch
static COleDateTime epoch( 2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 );

// Convert to integer
COleDateTime someTime;    // initialize it from somewhere
__int64 nOleDateTimeAsInt = static_cast<__int64>( (someTime - epoch).totalSeconds() );

// Create from integer
COleDateTimeSpan span( nOleDateTimeAsInt / SecondsInDay,
    (nOleDateTime % SecondsInDay) / SecondsInHour,
    (nOleDateTime % SecondsInHour) / SecondsInMinute,
    (nOleDateTime % SecondsInMinute) );
COleDateTime someTime( epoch + span );
```

Comment: If you use an epoch of 1970-01-01 you'll match [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: @MarkRansom I just need an epoch it can be any time, but you are right, `1970-01-01` is kind of a holy date for C programmers and POSIX time

Comment: Note that the correct function call is `GetTotalSeconds()` and not `totalSeconds()`. Not sure if the API changed since the answer was posted to now. [Link to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb7yw6f3.aspx#coledatetimespan__gettotalseconds)